# XML file loaded as a string

Tags: c#

I have noticed some code that I wrote a few years back and whilst thinking about optimizations I thought that this maybe an area that could be improved. I have the following:

```
var xml = new StringBuilder("");
foreach (var product in products)
{
xml.Append(product.AsXML());  // gives an xml string.
}
return String.Format("<products>{0}</products>", xml);
```

The xml string could be very large as the number of products in a database increase, I am wondering if there is a better way to do this.

JD

Comment: Obviously, the return line could avoid the string and be done on the StringBuilder (I would, for consistency's sake if nothing else).

Comment: Other than that, what need have you of keeping the whole thing as a String? Couldn't you be writing directly to a stream?

Comment: Originally there was a web service that the string would be passed to. That has been removed now. Would it be far faster or more memory efficient if I use a stream?

Answer (score 1):

I would use Linq to XML [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/07/using-linq-to-xml-and-how-to-build-a-custom-rss-feed-reader-with-it.aspx.)

You could try something like this:

```
    var prod = new List<string>();
    prod.Add("Apples");
    prod.Add("Oranges");
    var doc = new XElement("Product");
    foreach(String p in prod){


        doc.Add(new XElement("products", p));
    }

    Debug.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
```

outputs like this

```
<Product>
  <products>Apples</products>
  <products>Oranges</products>
</Product>
```

This mean you are no mucking around with Strings.

Cheers

Iain

Comment: Thanks Iain, but unless I profile it, would it be any faster?

Comment: It would make tighter code, using an api designed for working with XML, but you looking at micro optimizing it, for very little gain.

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic way to represent that piece of code using LINQ to XML would look more like this:

```
var element = new XElement("products",
                  products.Select(p => XElement.Parse(p.AsXml())));

return element.ToString();
```

Though it is better suited for situations where you can represent the XML in memory.  If not, I believe your best option is to use an XmlWriter.